# Custom component in SXA hidden in toolbox

Tags: sxa, best-practices

I am having issue adding new custom feature to page in SXA.

Steps I followed:

1. Created custom area for toolbox by adding feature in system->settings->features->custom features.
2. Next, I cloned existing promo rendering to the custom folder under layout->rendering->feature->custom features.
3. Last I added custom feature rendering to 'available renderings' under presentation.

After following these steps, when I tried to add the custom promo to page, it is not showing up. After checking presentation details, I see custom promo under final layout, not shared layout.

I am using `Sitecore 9.0.1` with `SXA 1.6`. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **Clone rendering** feature for that.

https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_accelerator/setting_up_and_configuring/configuring/copy_and_customize_an_sxa_rendering

section: **Copy and customize a rendering**

It will take care of everything, doing this manually is difficult and unnecessary with the new feature.

**EDIT:**

I think 1.6 is missing some auto-steps.

1. Make sure that you have your custom CSS class or use old (`promo` is defaul class for Promo rendering)
   [image]
2. Assign your rendering to compatible renderings variants or create new node
   [image]

Comment: I used script to clone rendering. I followed the exact steps. Which log files will have this info?

Comment: Sitecore log files.

Comment: I have tried the same scenario and end up like this -> https://imgur.com/a/E0P5o. If we are cloning rendering, I would assume that it at least looks and works the same as normal Promo.

Comment: I extended my answer. There are some steps that were not automated.

Comment: This is indeed working as expected :) Good catch @AlanPłócieniak ;) Will this be in SXA 1.7?

Comment: This is definitely right answer

Comment: I must be doing something wrong. Even after all following all steps, I am still not seeing the promo rendering on page. Would you mind creating screencast it? Are you copying the rendering promo.cshtml or inheriting it? Thank you very much.